# Is there a way to use MarkerCluster points to create a heatmap?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a list of points clustered together, and I'm using MarkerCluster to group them together.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbYZQ.png

I want to add a heatmap layer to the map, essentially showing how densely points are clustered visually. I can't seem to find a way to do this though, the heatmap plugins I've looked at all require intensity values, but my data is simply lat/long values.

Is there a way to use the number of points generated by MarkerCluster as an intensity value to generate a heatmap?